# Apache RewriteRule is not redirecting to www

Tags: apache-2.4

Using apache 2.4 and my site is on [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), which automatically gets redirected to https://www.example.com, wherein it is fully accessible and functional.

However, when I explicitly try using http://example.com or https://example.com, I get greeted by a placeholder page.

What I would like to happen is to redirect non-www to www. Ex (https://example.com -> https://www.example.com

I have set up a rewrite rule in my .conf file, but for some reason, it's not working. All I'm seeing is a placeholder page when accessing non www.

```
<VirtualHost <ip>:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    # Redirect to www
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost <ip>:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias example.com
    SSLCertificateFile /home/admin/certs/www_example_com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/admin/certs/www_example_com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /home/admin/certs/DigiCertCA.crt
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2 -TLSv1.1 -TLSv1 -SSLv3 -SSLv2
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
    # redirect to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to activate RewriteEngine.

```
    RewriteEngine on
```

Comment: Added the RewriteEngine on to the vhost for https traffic, I still get the placeholder page, and not getting redirected to www, when accessing http://example.com or https://example.com